# Trouble with running myprogram.exe as service on windows 2008

Tags: windows, windows-services

The MyProgram.exe is made to listen the request from pipe and using command prompt its working perfect but I tried to work it by using windows service but not success I have tried following steps on windows server 2008 enterprise:

```
> sc create MyService binPath= "C:\test\MyProgram.exe" DisplayName= "MyProgramService"
>[SC] CreateService SUCCESS

>sc start MyService 
[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

[reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192)

So I read on one blog that we need to create registry entry for the same then I tried the following steps

> I found my newly created service under: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\MyService
>
> 1. Click the key named MyService (it looks like a folder) from the menu in regedit. Select “edit” and “new” and then select “key.” This will create a new key which you should name “Parameters.” Next, right- click on the key that you just named “Parameters” and select “new” and then “string value.” Name the value “Application.” Double-click the string value and a box will pop up. In the box under “value data”, you need to put the full path to the Dropbox. In my case, the path was: C:\test\MyProgram.exe\MyProgram.exe
> 2. Start your new service. Navigate to the services list in the control panel‘s administrative tools or simply type services.msc in the run box. Find DropBox in the list and start it. New services should be set to start automatically, but feel free to check it to be sure.

But the service start for a few seconds and get terminated. When I start manually service from services.msc it give error

> StartService FAILED 1053:
>
> The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Not sure why any one have work on it, please guidance to make it as service.

Comment: What language did you use to write the service? Are you responding to the Service Control Manager to let it know that you have started?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Hi i didnt use any language its windows stander service sc.exe http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192

Comment: Did you not write C:\test\MyProgram.exe\MyProgram.exe ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't run just any EXE as a Windows service. You must have an exe which understands what it means to be a service and which communicates appropriately with the Windows Service Control Manager.

Refer to the Microsoft documentation, starting with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686953(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: [Microsoft's SRVANY](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSrvany) should help.

Comment: Thanks Chris and CoreTech