# py2exe binary with win service does not start when using sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, py2exe

My binary generated from py2exe which is a windows service and namedpipe fails to start, the change what i made in my project is "import sqlite3" and data base actions ( like insert, update, etc). is this causing my binary not to start , how do i fix this .

Comment: Run the binary from command line and tell us what the output is please.

Comment: [SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

    The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. This is the error that i am getting.

Comment: First things first: It's impossible to debug your problem unless you provide the code that is failing, all relevant error codes and tracebacks and anything that you think might contribute to the problem. There are also [plenty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206597/service-wont-start-under-windows-7-failed-1053) [of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560727/trouble-with-running-myprogram-exe-as-service-on-windows-2008) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793731/starting-a-windows-service-fails-with-error-1053?lq=1) regarding your error message on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. The issue was with import of a module. There was nothing got to do with sqlite3.